# C _setjmp: expected expression before ‘{’ token

Tags: c

I'm currently reverse engineering an old project I lost the source code to. Everything but this one line seems to be fine. What am I doing wrong?

```
int32_t v1 = _setjmp ({(struct {int32_t e0 [8]; int32_t e1; struct _TYPEDEF___sigset_t e2;}){
    //code here
}});
```

Comment: It looks like a compound literal inside a (non-standard) gcc expression statement.  Are you using gcc or clang as your compiler?

Comment: @NateEldredge Using GCC.

Comment: Oh wait, there's one `(` less than I was seeing.  So no, this is invalid syntax even for gcc. If you wrote this code, it's just wrong.  If it came out of a decompiler, the decompiler is broken or else it's deliberately only producing pseudocode.

Comment: But just knowing that it's `setjmp`, you know that it's expecting a `jmp_buf`, so why bother trying to parse the decompiler output any further?